# How to track ip adress of a computer performing db operations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, session, ip

I am storing sessions for all those admins who login and logout from my website , also i want to store their ip address , i am using asp.net mvc and c# is language . . . 
how do i capture their ip adress?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using `Request.UserHostAddress`. This would return the ip-address for the current user.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I would use JavaScript to populate a hidden field on the login form with their IP address.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json){
      document.getElementById("hiddenIpField").value=json.ip;
    }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```

Comment: Note that a javascript solution is particularly easy to manipulate. A hidden field can simply be changed before the POST occurs.

Comment: True @Rowan, but you can always have the code run in an onsubmit event handler.